# Can I use an ActiveRecord scope as an instance method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, named-scope

I have a scope that acts as a filter. For instance:

```
class User
  scope :in_good_standing, -> { where(:some_val => 'foo', :some_other_val => 'bar' }
end
```

Because `in_good_standing` depends on more than one condition, I'd like to have this defined on an instance of `User` as:

```
def in_good_standing?
  some_val == 'foo' && some_other_val == 'bar'
end
```

However, I'd really like to avoid duplicating the logic between both the instance method and the named scope. Is there a way to define `#in_good_standing?` in a way that simply refers to the scope?

#### edit

I realize these are very different concepts (one is a class method, one is an instance method), hence my question. As @MrDanA mentioned in a comment, the closest I can get is to check whether or not the record I'm curious about exists within the larger scope, which is probably the answer I'm looking for.

The responses about separating out different scopes from my example are useful, but I'm looking for a general pattern to apply to an application with some very complicated logic being driven by scopes.

Comment: As @meagar stated, you can't, because they are doing very different things. The most you could do is have your instance method call the scope and check to see if it's part of the returned results. However that won't work if the instance has not been saved yet. So in your method you could do: `User.in_good_standing.where(:id => self.id).present?`

Comment: As per your edit, I can add my comment as an answer if that worked for you.

Comment: Yes, I'd love your comment as an answer. thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adding my original comment as an answer:

As @meagar stated, you can't, because they are doing very different things. The most you could do is have your instance method call the scope and check to see if it's part of the returned results. However that won't work if the instance has not been saved yet. So in your method you could do:

```
User.in_good_standing.where(:id => self.id).present?
```

Comment: This works, but remember that you'll be doing a database query for this, and that can lead to expensive N+1. When I need something like this (imagine `scope :active, -> { where("expired_at > ?", Time.current) }`, I usually define the scope and repeat it's condition as an instance method (`def active?; self.expired_at > Time.current; end`); it's not DRY, and if one changes the scope he must remember to also change the instance method (and vice-versa), but your instance method won't issue any extra database calls.

Answer (score 12):

`Scopes` are nothing but `class methods`.You can define it like this

```
def self.in_good_standing?
  #your logic goes here
end
```

Comment: I never thought it this way and it helped a lot.

Comment: But you still can't call a class method on an instance like this: `user = User.find(3); user.in_good_standing?`, so this answer does not help much.

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't. One is building a database query, one is working with members of an instantiated object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can call the scope from an instance method.

I have been able to call a scope from an instance method using the following pattern:

```
# Model
class Obj
  # using numeric ids for this example
  # simple scope to return an instance of the record with an id == 1
  scope :get_first_record, -> { find(1) }

  def call_scope
    # I feel using self.class shows the intent of an instance calling its own Class methods, for readability
    self.class.get_first_record
  end
end

# Obj.count => 100
obj = Obj.create # obj.id => 101
obj.call_scope.id # = 1
```

Having the search logic buried inside a class method could later call for a refactor to allow that logic to be reused elsewhere like in 
[Mrdana](https://stackoverflow.com/users/744346/mrdana)'s answer.

Therefor, we could do that refactor using my example above, the original scope and using [Pavan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2346461/pavan)'s point, Mrdana's answer can be rewritten as a scope:

```
class User
  scope :in_good_standing, -> { where(:some_val => 'foo', :some_other_val => 'bar' }
  scope :users_in_good_standing, -> (users = all) { find(users.map(&:id)).in_good_standing } # same as: User.in_good_standing.where(:id => self.id) when self is the variable

  def in_good_standing?
    self.class.users_in_good_standing(self).present? 
  end
end
```

This keeps the code DRY, loosely coupled, reusable and extendable; while calling the scope from an instance method.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to DRY this up, you'd probably need to use a class method instead of a scope (as pavan alludes to). The class method can act the same as a scope and will allow you to use a common bit of code for determining the attributes and values (such as a hash constant?).

But I'd recommend against doing this. This level of abstraction for the sake of DRYness may be a bit over the top. It seems to me that your instance method could be broken up into simpler messages... e.g. `good_some_val?` and `good_some_other_val?`. Also because comparing on strings is generally bad / brittle. Anyway, in general, I'd expect you'd want to evolve your object methods and scopes differently. Scopes are the way they are because you're querying a database. So be it for that, but let your objects continue to pass the best messages possible!